# removing dead variables using antlr

Tags: vba, ms-access, antlr, antlr3

I am currently servicing an old VBA (visual basic for applications) application. I've got a legacy tool which analyzes that application and prints out dead variables. As there are more than 2000 of them I do not want to do this by hand.

Therefore I had the idea to transform the separate codefiles which contain the dead variable according to the aforementioned tool to ASTs and remove them that way.

My question: Is there a recommended way to do this?
I do not want to use StringTemplate, as I would need to create templates for all rules and if I had a commend on the hidden channel, it would be lost, right?
Everything I need is to remove parts of that code and print out the rest as it was read in.

Any one has any recommendations, please?

Comment: A variable might not be consulted for the final output, which is one form of dead.  Or it might be declared but never used. How do you know the variables are dead?   What does "remove" mean? Take out all code that computes a particular variable?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for trying to help me. I already chose to go for another resolution --> I did it by hand. Wasn't that much work, but I'd have loved the automated way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Some theory**

I assume that regular expressions are not enough to solve your task. That is you can't define the notion of a dead-code section in any regular language and expect to express it in a context-free language described by some antlr grammar.

**The algorithm**

The following algorithm can be suggested:

1. **Tokenize source code with a lexer.**
   Since you want to preserve all the correct code -- don't skip or hide it's tokens. Make sure to define separate tokens for parts which may be removed or which will be used to determine the dead code, all other characters can be collected under a single token type. Here you can use output of your auxiliary tool in predicates to reduce the number of tokens generated. I guess antlr's tokenization (like any other tokenization) is expressed in a regular language so you can't remove all the dead code on this step.
2. **Construct AST with a parser.**
   Here all the powers of a context-free language can be applied -- define dead-code sections in parser's rules and remove it from the AST being constructed.
3. **Convert AST to source code.** You can use some tree parser here, but I guess there is an easier way which can be found observing `toString` and similar methods of a tree type returned by the parser.